# Azure DevOps collection level custom groups

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to create new collection level custom group which members would see all projects under my organisation but could not set access rights in organisation or projects unless added to project admins. However, I do not find any place where I could restrict access to user access for this group members. Also I cannot find anything that would give automatically access to all projects. However, the project collection administrators group has this permission but it is not visible anywhere.
[image: group permissions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such permission to control users would see all projects (exclude Public projects) under organisation. You have to add the users to the projects, at least add to `Readers` group, then they can see the team projects.

You could add a [group rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/assign-access-levels-and-extensions-by-group-membership?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page), add the users in this group, and then assign all team projects to them.

[image]

More details of Permissions, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Comment: Does that same go with access management? I did not see that either anywhere?

Comment: Yes, group rule assigns an access level, and adds users to team projects and other specific groups. If the users need to be assigned different access level, you can create two group rules. Group rules is under Organization settings -- Users tab.